# Firestore - add array of objects

Tags: android, firebase, flutter

I'm having trobule with adding Array of Objects (tables) to Array of objects(restaurants). By that i mean, that I have following Firestore structure:

```
... (other data)
restaurants: [
   0: {
      name: name_0
      ...
      tables: [
          0: { no_chairs: 5, ... },
      ]
   },
   ...
]
```

I know how to add new object to restaurants, but I'm having trouble with adding new restaurant if tables list contains any data.

My code rn:

```
    var collection = firestore.collection('usersData')
        .doc(this.currentUser.uid).collection('buisness').doc('restaurants');
    collection.update({
      'restaurants': FieldValue.arrayUnion([restaurant.toJson()]),
    }).then( ... // reaction based on api answer
```

```
class Restaurant:
     Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    'name': name,
    ...
    'tables': tables!=null? [tables] : [], // I think that I should modify this line
  };

class Table:
    Map<String, dynamic> toJson()=> { // Or this method / use another
    'no_chairs': no_chairs,
    ...
  };
```

Is there any simple way to do it? Preferably without modyfing firestore file structure, but if it is necessary I'm willing to do it.

---

Extra question:
How to modify object in tables list? For example I want to change no_chairs to 7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your code above, the line below has a problem:

```dart
'tables': tables!=null? [tables] : [],
```

This part `[tables]` means you're putting the list `tables` as an element of the outer list.

To illustrate, if `tables` was as shown below:

```dart
List<int> tables = [1, 2, 3];
```

Then, `[tables]` is this:

```dart
[[1, 2, 3]]
```

**Solution**:

You can just use the `tables` variable directly since you're sending a list.

Before sending your `tables` object, you need to convert it to a list of Maps from the list of `TableModel` that is currently is (according to your comment below).

So you can modify your code to this:

```dart
'tables': tables != null ? tables.map((TableModel table) => table.toJson()).toList() : [],
```

> Extra question: How to modify object in tables list? For example I
> want to change no_chairs to 7

**Solution**:
You will have to get the actual list of restaurants and modify the exact table object you want and set the modified list to Firestore.

```dart
 var collection = firestore.collection('usersData').doc(this.currentUser.uid).collection('buisness').doc('restaurants');

 //Get list of restaurants
 List<Restaurant> restaurantList = ((await collection.get()).data()).map((dynamic restaurantJson) => Restaurant.fromJson(restaurantJson)).toList();

 Set number of chairs
 //
 restaurantList[restaurantIndex].tables[tableIndex].no_chairs = 7; //This assumes the no_chairs field is not final

 //Set list 
 collection.set({
   "restaurants": restaurantList.toJson()
 })
```

Comment: Without [] I get error:
Failed to add restaurant: Invalid argument: Instance of 'TableModel' as response from firebase

Comment: Alright, I'll make an update with a fix for this.

Comment: @next_99, please check out the updated answer.

Comment: Works great. Could you also help with extra question? - Editing value?